# I need a block that can combine a movement program with NXTbee radio

Tags: nxt, programming, bluetooth, labview

I am a student. I am working on a science project using LEGO Mindstorms robots enhanced with NXTbees creating a mesh network.

My engineering mentor has me using LabVIEW. I am trying to find a block that can combine a movement program (senses a block in the robot path, stops, then change direction) with NXTbee radio.

I want the NXTbee to override the Bluetooth in the LEGO Mindstorms program. I have tried a number of avenues seeking help, but they haven't worked out.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

There is a LabVIEW block for the NXTBee. For example, here is a [tutorial](http://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/tutorial-nxtbee-in-labview-for-lego-mindstorms-lvlm/) from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

For mesh you will need the series 2 XBee's I think. It is doable by putting the series 1 to broadcast mode, but series 2 can do real mesh.